# DSolve не работает с простыми примерами

Tags: математика, mathematica

**Wolfram Mathematica 14.0.0**
Ошибка отсутствия аргументов у функции у, хотя я приписываю y[x].

DSolve[y'[x] == x, y[x], x]

DSolve::dvnoarg: The function y appears with no arguments.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С уравнениями 2 порядка все работает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://i123.fastpic.org/big/2024/0221/e1/2f28a08a288bcb33e5b3da978eae82e1.jpg Вы правильно внесли символ производной, например?...

Comment: @Harry с производной второго порядка все работает и если я просто хочу получить производную например x^2, но с уравнением первого порядка не работает

Comment: Гм... я этим микроскопом все больше гвозди забиваю, так что откровенно говоря, никаких идей. Может, какие определения до этого сработали? Если закрыть-открыть и в чистом окне, то как тогда?...

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю с чем это связано, но я просто заменил обозначение y[x] на u[x] и все заработало.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]